# Modifying files on remote Ubuntu server from Windows PC

Tags: windows, linux, synchronization

I am developing some Python programs that I'm running on a remote Ubuntu Linux server (hosted on Slicehost). I would like to work on the source in an IDE on my Windows Vista PC, and have all file modifications sent directly to the Linux box without my intervention (i.e. without having to manually SFTP the files each time I change them). What is the very easiest way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PuTTy](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and [SFTPDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/sftpdrive).

PuTTy is an SSH client, and SFTPDrive ($39 USD) will allow you to mount your remote file system locally as a drive letter.

Comment: No worries. Interesting product, not come across it before.

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP includes a [basic remote file editor](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_editor), though if you want to use a proper IDE for your development this won't be much help.

I'd suggest you run a version control system like [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), which would allow you to write a [post-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html#svn-ch-5-sect-2.1) to automatically [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) your code the server with each commit.

Comment: WinSCP is good, but will not allow you to access the files through your IDE like SFTPDrive does

Answer (score 1):

Install Samba and OpenVPN on the server, and OpenVPN on the client.  Setup Samba to share the directory tree you're interested in, and access it over the VPN for security.  Perhaps Vista has non-sucky WebDAV support by now, and you could use WebDAV over HTTPS, but it was always crap under XP.

Ben's suggestion of a local dev environment using a VM is also a winner.

Answer (score 0):

You could install cygwin and then have rsync run on cron every minute.

Or you could use Netdrive to access the server via FTP like a local disk:

http://tech.xptechsupport.com/netdrive-turn-your-ftp-into-a-drive-letter.html

Or you may be able to achieve something similar using cygwin and FUSE - you can on linux, but never tried it on cygwin.

Also, would it not be easier to set up a full dev environment locally? Maybe using a virtual machine? It'll be much quicker for testing. And then you can set up a shell script to transfer the current version to the slicehost server.